# Invalid input leads to psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I keep getting an error and I'm not sure whats triggering it. In my terminal I get Error 500 get /artists/none" Another line it says

sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type integer: "None"
LINE 3: WHERE artist.id = 'None'

```
@app.route('/artists/<artist_id>')
def show_artist(artist_id):
  selectedArtist = Artist.query.filter_by(id=artist_id).first()
  related_shows = Shows.query.filter_by(related_artist=artist_id).all()
  upcoming_shows = []
  upcoming_shows_count = 0
  past_shows = []
  past_shows_count = 0
  for show in related_shows:
    if show.start_time > datetime.now():
      upcoming_shows_count += 1
      upcoming_shows.append({
        'venue_id': show.venue.id,
        'venue_name': show.venue.name,
        'venue_image_link':show.venue.image_link,
        'start_time': format_datetime(str(show.start_time))
      })
    elif show.start_time < datetime.now():
      past_shows_count += 1
      past_shows.append({
        'venue_id': show.venue.id,
        'venue_name': show.venue.name,
        'venue_image_link':show.venue.image_link,
        'start_time': format_datetime(str(show.start_time))
      })
  data = {
    'id': selectedArtist.id,
    'name':selectedArtist.name,
    'city': selectedArtist.city,
    'state': selectedArtist.state,
    'phone': selectedArtist.phone,
    'website': selectedArtist.website,
    'facebook_link': selectedArtist.facebook_link,
    'image_link': selectedArtist.image_link,
    'upcoming_shows': upcoming_shows,
    'upcoming_shows_count':upcoming_shows_count,
    'past_shows_count': past_shows_count,
    'past_shows': past_shows
  }
  return render_template('pages/show_artist.html', artist=data)
```

It returns the artist template but I get this error in my shell, eventually the app times out, and nothing in the artists section works. Once I restart the local server it works again. I can't seem to find out what triggering it. Any clues?

Comment: What is the input? It looks like it's missing if you get `None`.

Comment: the input is artist_id. it works though. The template loads properly. In my shell it will show the get method for the selected artist, and then immeditaly under another GET method showing none.

Comment: Somehow a `None` is sneaking through. Maybe you need to trap for that condition and handle that somehow differently? You could always render a different page and bail out. Someone's going to type in `sdhfisdfghsdbfg` eventually anyway.

Comment: There is an html template that is displaying a list of artists, the user clicks on the name and another template loads through this script. The user never types anything for it. The bizarre thing is that it works! And often times it works for a few rounds and then I get the double get.

Comment: What I mean is they could hack around with the URL and type in whatever, you can't prevent that, so you need to defend against invalid inputs. Maybe you have a bad link somewhere on the page. It could be as simple as an image with `href=""` which will just load the base URL as an image.

Comment: I see. I just type in any id and got a whole bunch of errors. What do you recommend as good practice?

Comment: Have guard conditions at the start of that function to check for valid inputs, and if any fail, render some kind of sensible error page. It helps if you also return some kind of appropriate [HTTP error code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) like 400 for garbage input or 404 for a missing record. You do *assume* that this `SELECT` will succeed, and it might not.